# Inserting data to another table based on some criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

- Client: clientid, latt, long
- Region: Regionid, latt, long

I want transfer `Regionid` from `Region` to `Client`, where `latt` and `long` columns are matched.

Here is my code. I have no idea what to do:

```
INSERT INTO Client (Region)
SELECT Region.Regionid
FROM Region
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.Latt = Region.Latt
    AND Client.Long = Region.Long
WHERE Client.Latt = Region.Latt
    AND Client.Long = Region.Long
```

Should I create a `Region` column in `Client` table first?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You HAVE to create column Region in client first:

```
ALTER TABLE client ADD region int;
```

Change int to something else if regionId in table regio is of other type

Then you probably want to UPDATE instead of insert,

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.region = r.regionId
FROM client c
INNER JOIN region r ON c.latt = r.latt AND c.long = r.long
```

After the `UPDATE` you can drop the `latt` and `long` columns to have your tables normalized

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee9b4)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I'll increment your reputation as soon as I have enough reputation to do so

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed add another column to your Client table, let's just call it Region.

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT
ADD REGION INTEGER
```

This will add the column to your table, then just do a UPDATE on that column like:

```
UPDATE C
SET Region = R.RegionID
FROM Region R
INNER JOIN CLIENT C ON C.LATT = R.LATT AND C.LONG = R.LONG
```

You don't need the conditions in the `WHERE` clause anymore, because they are implicit in the `JOIN` as they are the same conditions.